# Initialized attibute is null in another function

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I encounter an error and i think the problem is the fact that apex is asynchronous. Here the explanation.

From my component i call the method doAction:

```
<aura:attribute name="value" type="List"/>
<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doAction}" value="{!this}"/>
```

This method call an apex class to select the highest value in my table with a simple select MAX

```
doAction : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log("getMostWished");
    var action = component.get("c.getMostWished");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            console.log("MostWished");
            component.set("v.value", response.getReturnValue())
        }
        else {
            console.log("getMostWished failed with state: " + state);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

So this value must be stored into 'v.value' but later in my code when I use it, v.value is null.

On the console browser, the console.log("MostWished"); is displayed in last but some logs who are later in the code are displayed first.

I use v.value in a second component

```
<c:barGraph products="{!prod}" value="{!v.value}"/>
```

In this component, i call findMax method

```
<aura:attribute name="value" type="Object"/>
<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.findMax}" value="{!this}"/>
```

for the moment findMax is just here as debug with console.log. Those console.log are displayed before the MostWished above and the console.dir say the v.value is null.

```
findMax : function(component, event, helper) {
        var val = component.get("v.value");
        console.log('ICI');
        console.dir(val);
    }
```

does exist a way to wait for the value, stop the execution a moment or tell my program 'Wait the end of method doAction'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's null because the init function is called before the data gets back from the server. Most likely, you want to set a change handler instead:

```
<aura:attribute name="value" type="Object" />
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.value}" action="{!c.findMax}" />
```

Whenever a change is detected in value, your findMax function should be called. See [Detecting Data Changes with Change Handlers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_data_change.htm) and [aura:valueChange](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_valueChange.htm).

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what i needed. and thank you to have shared the good corresponding documentation with your answer.